# Rotate Animation is not working?

Tags: wpf, animation

I have created one Storyboard with 
1.Rotate
2.Scale
3.Opacity Animations

And applied this storyboard to ellipse(like circle(width and Height are equal) when the ToggleButton is clicked ,All animation are working but Rotate is not working.

My Requirement is 
1.First it rotate
2.Scale the x and y(from 1 to 0.2) then
3.Opacity goes to zero

My plan to achieve the same behavior of Radial Menu.

```
XAML:

<Storyboard x:Key="enterStoryBoard">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="180"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="0.2"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="0.2"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

    </Storyboard>

  <Grid>
        <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Margin="132,96,192,46" Stroke="#FF8300FF" StrokeThickness="35" Width="300" Height="300" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Ellipse.RenderTransform>

        </Ellipse>           
        <ToggleButton x:Name="toggle" Content="Click" Click="Button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 30 60 0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <ToggleButton.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <Ellipse Width="50" Height="50" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2"/>
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Grid>                        
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ToggleButton.Template>
        </ToggleButton>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: any code sample maybe ?

Answer (score 3):

something like this works fine for me to do all three(rotate, opacity, scale) animations that you require from a single `Storyboard`

```
<Grid Margin="15">
  <Grid.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click"
                  SourceName="myBtn">
      <EventTrigger.Actions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
          <Storyboard>
            <!--  Rotate  -->
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.4"
                              From="0"
                              Storyboard.TargetName="myEllipse"
                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                              To="180" />
            <!--  Opacity  -->
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.4"
                              From="1"
                              Storyboard.TargetName="myEllipse"
                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.Opacity)"
                              To="0" />
            <!--  Scale Transform - X  -->
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.4"
                              From="1"
                              Storyboard.TargetName="myEllipse"
                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                              To="0.2" />
            <!--  Scale Transform - Y  -->
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.4"
                              From="1"
                              Storyboard.TargetName="myEllipse"
                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                              To="0.2" />
          </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
      </EventTrigger.Actions>
    </EventTrigger>
  </Grid.Triggers>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Canvas Grid.Row="0">
    <Ellipse x:Name="myEllipse"
              Canvas.Left="100"
              Canvas.Top="100"
              Width="50"
              Height="80"
              Fill="Tomato"
              Opacity="1"
              Stroke="SteelBlue">
      <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
          <RotateTransform Angle="0"
                            CenterX="25"
                            CenterY="45" />
          <ScaleTransform CenterX="25"
                          CenterY="40" />
        </TransformGroup>
      </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
    </Ellipse>
  </Canvas>
  <Button x:Name="myBtn"
          Grid.Row="1"
          Margin="0 10 0 0"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          Content="Click Me" />
</Grid>
```

**Update:**

Firstly, I'm not sure of what this Radial Menu is that your talking about so not sure what animation that control has.

Now couple points:

- From your `Storyboard` edit all your animations run for 0.4 seconds and start together. hence there really is no need to use a `KeyFrames` animation since you can just use the standard `DoubleAnimation` to achieve the same result.
- When you can do something from xaml, prefer to do it from xaml alone. You do not need to have a Click handler on your `ToggleButton` in your mentioned case since that can be achieved as I had shown from xaml alone.

I tweaked the numbers in my posted code to match your numbers, I strongly advice you try out the posted code firstly and then tweak to your requirements. While your question started with you having problems with having a concurrent `RotateAnimation`, it's now gone to a case of "pls write all the code for me". It's not going to help you in the long run. Get a book on WPF and read some into Animation basics

Comment: @Ravuthasamy well you can tweak the numbers yourself can't you? If your not sure then you need to give more info. Like rotate by how much? 360deg? are all three simulatneous or is it one after the other?

Comment: i given some info in my post(Storyboard),i want to achieve the same behavior of Radial Menu.I started storyboard when the ToggleButton is clicked.

Comment: @Ravuthasamy I updated my code snippet to match your `Storyboard`. Please use that as a "reference". See how it works and modify it to your requirement. If you have new questions then "create" a new question than add stuff to the same one.